# Ensure number of RDD elements are equal

Tags: scala, apache-spark, map-function

After a lot of RDD operations, I now have a clean comma separated data set. But the number of elements in each row RDD is not equal.

```
ABCD,A,M@L,79,80,a
BGDA,F,D@L,89,9,b
SDAA,D,D@I,1,9,c
SWQA,E,D@I,2,0
TYA,E,D@I,2
RQA,E,D@I,2,12


val cleanedRDD = inputRDD
        .flatMap(line  => line._1.split("\n")) //split at newline
        .filter { x => !x.startsWith("#") && !x.startsWith("Worst") &&   !x.startsWith("Hold")} //filter out headers
        .map { x => x.drop(9) } //clean up chars
        .map (x => x.replaceAll(reg, ",")) //replace all consecutive spaces
        .filter(x=> !x.isEmpty())
```

How can I map the above rdd to add extra comma separators where values dont exit?

Thanks,rt

Comment: Adding comma separators won't help since you replace them all in the final map? Have you not given the code you're actually using, since I think the code you show ends up with one element per row, a String?

Comment: Yes Paul. Each row is a comma separated string that I plan to convert to dataframe later on. But first I got to fix the number of comma separated elements per row string.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a spark question, just string manipulation

I think the easiest way to ensure you get `n` fields back is to add `n` extra commas to the string, split it, and return the first `n`. So

```
def splitInto(s:String, n:Int) = (s + ","*n).split(",", -1).take(n)

splitInto("a,b,c,d", 4)                           //> Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)
splitInto("a,b,c", 4)                             //> Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, "")
splitInto("a,b", 4)                               //> Array[String] = Array(a, b, "", "")
splitInto("a", 4)                                 //> Array[String] = Array(a, "", "", "")
splitInto("", 4)                                  //> Array[String] = Array("", "", "", "")
```